# Java robot not working

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am working on a simple speech recognition project. I have a command called `scroll up` where I want to use the class to press the UP key.

This is the code:

```
        else if(resultText.equalsIgnoreCase("scroll up"))
        {
            try {
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                robot.delay(5000);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                robot.delay(1000);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                robot.delay(1000);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
            }
            catch (AWTException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I have already imported these

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

Now the same code works well in another project, but not in the present project. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is not working? syntax or runtime?

Comment: @MouseEvent When I say, 'scroll up', in the console it does display 'scroll up', but nothing happens, I mean it does not press the Up button.

Comment: The Kelsey events will be sent to the currently focused compnents. Also make sure you call keyRelease as well

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
else if (resultText.equalsIgnoreCase("scroll up")) {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(5000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);

        robot.delay(1000);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
        robot.delay(1000);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
        robot.delay(1000);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
```

You have to release the same button.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I understood that the input comes from command-line (an anytime very important fact to include in your post). this means that the command window (or console panel - in IDE) contains the system focus, theirfore UP does nothing.

Add a `requestFocus()` in your code, this should help.